# Java InetAddress.getByName.isReachable() Alternative

Tags: java, android, connection

I've using InetAddress.getByName.isReachable() for a while in my app in order to know if the mobile devices can reach the server. However this need permissions in Windows 7 and I would like to know if there is an alternative of doing this without the need of adding permissions on Windows 7 firewall.
Here is how I use it:

```
boolean isReachable = false;
    try{
        isReachable = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.13").isReachable(1000);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("InetAddress", e.getMessage());
}finally {
    if (isReachable) {
        new CreateCandidato().execute();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.errorserver, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Is there a better solution?
Thank you

Comment: u mean to say u need to check network connectivity?

Comment: I think network connectivity is only checking if Wi-Fi is turned on. What I want is to know if the devices can reach my Wamp Server.

Comment: Needs permission in Windows 7 why?

Comment: isReachable uses ICMP and TCP Port 7. by default the firewall in windows 7 blocks them afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should just try to connect and handle the `ConnectException` when and if it arises. These games where you try to foresee the future and guess what's going to happen are basically a waste of time. The best way to discover whether *any* resource is available is to try to use it. In this case:

1. The server could be responding to ICMP but not TCP at all.
2. The server could respond to ICMP or TCP port 7 but the service could still not be running.
3. The server could respond to ICMP or TCP port 7 and the service could be running at that instance but be down an instant later when you try to connect.
4. The server could not respond to ICMP or TCP port 7 but the server *could* be running.

Etc etc. Don't try to foretell the future.